# Modify default library search dirs that gcc passes to ld

Tags: gcc, ld

I want to force new GCC 12 on my old debian (that only has GCC 6 by default) to use fresh libstdc++ headers with new header-only features, but link with old stdlibc++,gcc_s (and other system/compiler libs used by GCC6) to keep binary compatibility with native runtime of old debian (so that users of old GCC6 can link with my binaries without having GCC12).
Of course I know that some functionality in the old runtime will be missing, and ABI is also different, but I guess I can fight with that. Afterall RedHat seems to be using similar scheme for their devtoolset packages (they try to link missing functionality of new runtime statically to your binary if these symbols are not found in native old runtime)

So far I am stuck with -L arguments that GCC is passing to ld.
Here is complete output of `/usr/local/gcc12/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 main.cpp -Wl,-v -v` command for simple hello-world main.cpp:
https://pastebin.com/JhYSfg4x

The question: **Where does GCC take all these -L paths from, and how do I remove/modify them? I don't want to accidentally link with new version of libraries that were built with GCC12**:

```
 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/gcc12/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/local/gcc12/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc -L/usr/local/gcc12/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../.. /tmp/ccXfhCs4.o
```

System ld.conf does not mention any paths to /usr/local/gcc12 folder.

-nostdlib and -nodefaultlibs are removing some standard -l flags, but they are not doing anything to -L flags.

Update: I ended up just removing all *.a, *.so*, *.la files from include, lib and lib64 folders of gcc12, and I also added -L path to native libraries. This way I am sure gcc12 can't pickup one of its libraries for li nking. Not sure if this is good solution, but it works.

Comment: "remote" as in "remove"?

Comment: @tadman, right, fixed.